# How to express multi-table join in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My query looks (a bit) like this:

```
SELECT
  t.strategy_id, SUM(t.price*t.qty), p.currency
FROM   
  trades t, products p
WHERE
  t.symbol = p.symbol and
  (DATE(trade_time) > '2015-01-01' and DATE(trade_time) < DATE(NOW()))
GROUP 
  BY t.strategy_id, SYMBOL, DATE(trade_time) WITH ROLLUP
```

How would I best express this in "Rails-y"? Since the result is a compound of fields from two tables, should I create a model StrategyPnl? Should it derive from ActiveRecord::Base? Probably not since there is is no table for it, or...?

Btw, I have no associations between these tables, is that a requirement?

I would like to write something like:

stratpnl.select().where().group()....

and get an array of this new class/model but I cant figure out how to do that?

************************* EDIT ***************************

I'm simplyfying the question since the actual tables aren't important in this question:

Assume two tables A and B with no relationships (FK or other)

```
SELECT A.FIELD_Y, B.FIELD_X
FROM A,B
WHERE A.INTEGER_X > B.INTEGER_Y
GROUP BY A.NAME
```

Is there any way I can express this query in Rails with nice models? I know I can do this:

```
@result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

but that will only give me a two-dimensional array of fields, I would prefer to use ActiveRecords functionalty and refer to objects and fields, since its there.

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.19

Comment: Share the model-relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the proper model-relationships, here's what you could do with ActiveRecord:

```
strategies_data = \
  Trade. # assuming at least one table has an associated model
  joins("INNER JOIN products ON products.symbol = trades.symbol").
  where("DATE(trade_time) BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.new(2015, 1, 1), Date.today).
  group("trades.strategy_id, trades.symbol, DATE(trade_time) WITH ROLLUP").
  select("trades.strategy_id AS id,
          SUM(trades.price*trades.qty) AS strategy_price,
          products.currency AS currency")
```

And then:

```
sd = strategies_data.first
sd.id #=> gives you strategy_id
sd.strategy_price #=> gives you total price
sd.currency #=> gives you the currency
```

With a bit of debugging, that should work.

**Update:**

And if you want things to be semantically correct as well (in terms of classes), add this step if you're fine with the slow-down:

```
strategy_columns = %i{id strategy_price currency}
strategy_struct = Struct.new(*strategy_columns)
strategies = \
  strategies_data.map do |sd|
    attributes = \
      strategy_columns.each_with_object({}) do |attr, hash|
        hash[attr] = sd.public_send(attr)
      end

    strategy_struct.new(attributes)
  end
```

Comment: OK sounds plausible, what exactly is strategies_data?

Comment: Just a variable. Pick your own name.

Comment: Yes, but is it instances of the Trade model? Shouldn't I create a new Model ?

Comment: Ah! Yeah, it'll be an instance of Trade::ActiveRecord_Relation. And unless you're calling trade-methods on this instance, you should be fine. But if this is something you're going to be routinely doing, then yeah, a separate model would make things a lot cleaner.

Comment: Using the main model is fine for this kind of needs, but if you need to be more semantic you can map them to new objects: `StrategiesData = Struct.new(:id, :price, :currency); strategies_data.map! { |sd| StrategiesData.new(sd.id, sd.price, sd.currency) }`; but usually the performance tradeoff is against this solution

Comment: It's weird, and it doesnt look right (The result should not be Trades!), but it seems to work, at least in part.. I guess it would look more "correct" if I  created a model StrategyPnl, set table_name to "trades" and then used the above code?!